# What is the purpose of the for iteration in the code?

Tags: matlab

I have a small code like this. Can anyone tell me what is the purpose of the for iteration?
I can see the result difference before and after the for iteration, I just cannot understand what is 
the purpose of the for iteration? Thanks a lot!

```
A = randn(n,m);   

    for i=1:m                  

        A(:,i) = A(:,i) / norm(A(:,i));
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ensuring that each column in `A` is normalised to have unit length.

`A(:,1)` gives you the first column of `A`, and `norm(A(:,1))` gives you the Euclidean norm (or length) of the vector defined by the first column of `A`.

The reason that you can't do `A=A/norm(A)` is because Matlab will calculate the matrix norm, not the norm of each column individually.

There is a Matlab builtin function that will do this for you: [`normc`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/nnet/ref/normc.html).

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me what is the advantage of normalizing a matrix to have unit length? And what is the purpose of zscore(A)? And what is the difference between them?

Comment: Presumably normalising the columns of a matrix is necessary for the algorithm it is part of! About the zscore, that's something best explained by an introductory statistics textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Like David said, it's giving each column unit length, and you can't do `A/norm(A)` for reasons he mentioned, but you can do:

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, A, sqrt(sum(A.^2,1)))
```

which is like virtually doing:

```
A ./ repmat(sqrt(sum(A.^2,1)),size(A,1),1)
```

On a side note, I would advise against assigning to the same variable while figuring out an expression.